# Multiple mat-tables and multiple different dataSources in one component, renderRows() not updating table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm looking to have n number of tables in one component with n number of different data sources, but with the same columns. These data sources need to be broken up. The user has a simple form that can add a new row to any one of those tables, and then from within the addRow function I will call renderRows() on that specific table. I'm using ViewChild to accomplish this, but for some reason only one of the n tables are actually updating on the fly when a row is added.

In the Stackblitz, what I want is that both tables look the exact same, so they have the same data and are rendered the same. When clicking the "Rerender" button, both tables should get a row added to their datasource.

This code is really close what I'm working with, and it also shows my problem. Here is the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-render-rows-1aelgx?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html,app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts
and in case that link doesn't work.

html

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="table_data">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-table #second_table [dataSource]="second_table_data">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
<button (click)="addRow()">ReRender</button>

<!-- Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```

ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Table with filtering
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-filtering-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-filtering-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-filtering-example.html',
})
export class TableFilteringExample {
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<Element>;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) second_table: MatTable<Element>;
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  table_data: any[] = [];
  second_table_data: any[] = [];

  addRow() {
    this.table_data.push(ELEMENT_DATA[this.table_data.length])
    this.second_table_data.push(ELEMENT_DATA[this.table_data.length])
    console.log(this.table_data)
    console.log(this.second_table_data)
    this.second_table.renderRows();
    this.table.renderRows();
  }
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];


/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the table by its template reference `@ViewChild('TemplateRef')` - https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description.

In your example, you are basically pushing the same data into the same table twice.

Update the following lines as shown below:

```
export class TableFilteringExample {
  @ViewChild('table') table: MatTable<Element>;
  @ViewChild('second_table') second_table: MatTable<Element>;

 . . .
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-render-rows-eme2cy?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html,app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts